# SQL. WITH. Наследование условий между табличными пространствами переходящими друг в друга

Tags: sql, oracle

Имеется следующий код на SQL

```
WITH 
  WithTable1 AS
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
    WHERE myFavoriteLang = 'golang'
  ),
  
  WithTable2 AS
  (
    SELECT 
    FROM WithTable1
    WHERE myFavoriteLang = 'javascript'
  )
SELECT *
FROM WithTable2;
```

Просьба проконсультировать по работе наследований условий между табличными пространствами.
Выборка в результирующем селекте по параметру **myFavoriteLang** по какому работает?

1. последнее дублирующее условие в **WithTable2** перезатрет старое значение из **WithTable2**
2. Эти условия дополнят друг друга. Единственное место где может быть удобно - это числовые, либо временные промежутки.

И вообще, есть ли какой то механизм изменения значения условия при наследовании между табличными пространствами как в описываемом коде?

Comment: а почему именованные подзапросы вы называете табличными пространствами?

Comment: спасибо за замечание. почему то раньше данные выражения называл табличными пространствами, хотя правильно называть обобщенным табличным выражением)

Comment: `обобщенным табличным выражением` - шо? это так "subquery factoring" на русский перевели?

Answer (score 1):

Табличное пространство - по сути отдельная таблица. Представьте, что вы сделали select с нужным условием и сохранили результат в другой таблице (собственно с именем пространства). Записей с не подошедшим условием в ней уже нет. Остальная часть запроса работает с этой "таблицей", так что ни о каком изменении условия постфактум речи идти не может. несколько условий на одно поле будут фактически объединяться по AND и лишь уменьшать выборку

Answer (score 0):

> Выборка в результирующем селекте по параметру myFavoriteLang по какому работает?

Оптимизатор раскроет запрос точно так же как сделал бы это со вьюшками.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1 t
WHERE
    t.myFavoriteLang = 'golang'
and t.myFavoriteLang = 'javascript';
```